# Customize log output in Kibana

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

Finally, I got working ELK stack to get some logs from a remote server. However, I would like to customize the output of the logs. Is there a way to remove some fields which I am highlighting in yellow:

[image]

I tried to remove them from _source including remove_field in the logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/..."
    ssl_key => "/..logstash.key"
  }
}

filter {
        grok {
            match => {
                "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "tags", "prospector.type", "host.architecture", "host.containerized", "host.id", "host.os.platform", "host.os.family" ]
        }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I get rid of the yellow fields in _source for the logs coming from filebeat?

Update of logstash.conf based on Leandro comments:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => ".../logstash.crt"
    ssl_key => ".../logstash.key"
  }
}

filter {
        grok {
            match => {
                "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "tags","[prospector][type]","[host][architecture]", "[host][containerized]", "[host][id]", "[host][os][platform]", "[host][os][family]", "[beat][hostname]", "[beat][name]", "[beat][version], "[offset]", "[input][type]", "[meta][cloud][provider]", "[meta][cloud][machine_type]", "[meta][cloud][instance_id]"]
        }
}



output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

In logs:

```
019-02-27T17:03:41.637-0800    DEBUG   [input] file/states.go:68       New state added for /logs/api.log
2019-02-27T17:03:41.637-0800    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:315      Registrar state updates processed. Count: 1
2019-02-27T17:03:41.637-0800    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:400      Write registry file: /filebeat/registry
2019-02-27T17:03:41.637-0800    INFO    log/harvester.go:255    Harvester started for file: /logs/api.log
2019-02-27T17:03:41.647-0800    DEBUG   [publish]       pipeline/processor.go:308       Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2019-02-28T01:03:41.647Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.6.0"
  },
  "log": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/logs/api.log"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "tomcat",
    "os": {
      "family": "redhat",
      "name": "CentOS Linux",
      "codename": "Core",
      "platform": "centos",
      "version": "7 (Core)"
    },
    "id": "6aaed308aa5a419f880c5e45eea65414",
    "containerized": true,
    "architecture": "x86_64"
  },
  "meta": {
    "cloud": {
      "region": "CanadaCentral",
      "provider": "az",
      "instance_id": "6452bcf4-7f5d-4fc3-9f8e-5ea57f00724b",
      "instance_name": "tomcat",
      "machine_type": "Standard_D8s_v3"
    }
  },
  "message": "2018-09-14 20:23:37 INFO  ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started",
  "source": "/logs/api.log",
  "offset": 0,
  "prospector": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "tomcat",
    "version": "6.6.0",
    "name": "tomcat"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those fields are nested fields, the way to access them in a Logstash filter is using the `[field][subfield]` notation.

Your `remove_field` shoud be  something like this:

```
remove_field => ["tags","[host][architecture]","[meta][cloud][provider]"]
```

But I don't think you can remove the `@version` field.

**UPDATE:**

Using the event example from your Filebeat log I simulated a pipeline and got a `_grokparsefailure`, to remove the fields even when the grok fails you need to use the `remove_field` inside a `mutate` filter:

```
filter {
  grok {
     your grok
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["[prospector]","[host][architecture]", "[host][containerized]", "[host][id]", "[host][os][platform]", "[host][os][family]", "[beat]", "[offset]", "[input]", "[meta]"]
  }
}
```

Don't remove the `tags` field until you have fixed your groks.

The logstash output on that example is:

```
{
  "source": "/logs/api.log",
  "tags": [
    "_grokparsefailure"
  ],
  "@timestamp": "2019-02-28T01:03:41.647Z",
  "message": "2018-09-14 20:23:37 INFO  ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started",
  "log": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/logs/api.log"
    }
  },
  "@version": "1",
  "host": {
    "os": {
      "codename": "Core",
      "version": "7 (Core)",
      "name": "CentOS Linux"
    },
    "name": "tomcat"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leandro, it makes sense to remove them like that. I've applied the changes but they are not reflected. I have restarted all the ELK stack and deleted registry and meta.json from filebeat. Do I need to do something else to see the changes in the fields?

Comment: The fields of documents already indexed won't be removed, only new documents will have the field removed using that logstash pipeline. If you still have the original logs you can index them again. Also, since it is inside of the grok, it will only work if the grok filter is successful, are you having any grokparsefailure tag?

Comment: I tried with different logs and the fields are still there in Kibana. I assume the grok filter works based on the logs included in the update of my question. I am not having any parse failure in the filebeat logs.

Comment: The log you posted is from filebeat, it is an event that it will publish to logstash where the filter will be applied and the fields removed, but using this event I simulated your pipeline and got a `_grokparsefailure`, also, you missed a `"` after `[beat][version]`. You could try to use the `remove_field` outside `grok`, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Leandro it worked. I just continue checking the grokparsefailure displayed in logstash.